Sumar.si.conjunto desde varios libros en google sheets
necesito ayuda con un proyecto, tengo 3 libros, cada uno de ellos contiene 1 hoja y mi intención es sumar una columna de esa hoja para cada libro, es decir, que me genere una cifra que consolide la sumatoria de los 3 libros, ahora bien, no me sirve que me sume toda la columna (porque esto ya lo logré) lo que necesito sume de acuerdo a ciertos criterios, por lo tanto habría que filtrar, es decir, requiero que solo me sume los que cumplen con el criterio de:
1:fecha
2:ingresos
3:tipo de producto
He intentado usar un sumar.si.conjunto pero no se me da como concatenar el intervalo de suma y de los criterios usando un importrange o concatenando la url del archivo y los rangos. Luego pensè que con un filter pero no he logrado juntar filter con importrange tampoco.
Me pueden proponer otra solución?

No sé entiende del todo lo que quieres hacer. Creo que es mejor colocar un ejemplo de los datos que tienen las hojas y el criterio específico que quieres que cumplan los registros que quieres sumar.

ciertamente ahora que lo veo no está redactada la pregunta de la mejor forma. Pero me fui por otra vía que estéticamente no era la que quería pero me dio resultado. En mi 4to libro, hice importrange de las 3 hojas de los 3 libros de donde quiero obtener los datos para la suma y luego pude usar sumar.si.conjunto dentro de ese mismo libro porque no implicaba indicar una url a un libro externo.

Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
